# Content-Type header value

Tags: php, http

What does `Content-Type` header field really mean in the request? Tho official [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) say

> tells the server what type of data is actually sent

But i'm a little confused here. If i'm right that setting different values of that filed doesn't influence the data format/shape but only informs the receiver (`php` script for e.g.) how to treat the data making it accessible in different ways like `php://input` or `$_POST` variable. So the data being send is always the same but the way it's accessible on the server is different based on `Content-Type` vale?

---

Why was my question downvoted? What's wrong with it?

Comment: No, of course the data is not always the same … Just because the Content-Type header for example says the data _was_ JSON, does not make completely arbitrary data _into_ JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in your understanding that the data format does not change based on the value of the "Content-Type" header. It is only an indication to the server, that the client is sending a particular type of content. It is up-to the server to decide how to process a particular type of data.